# How to inject external JS library into a module?

Tags: seedstack

I'm using SeedStack to create a web application. In order to do that, I use W20 to develop my frontend. I need specific JavaScript libraries into that project. How can I inject an external javascript library into it ? I want to use Chart.js http://www.chartjs.org/ to visualize data into charts. To do that, I suppose that I have to inject ChartJS as a dependency module in Angular.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting to the specific answer, please note that SeedStack already has an [add-on for charts](http://seedstack.org/addons/w20-dataviz/). As for integrating a library with W20, you have two main things to do:

- Configure RequireJS to load the JS file and be able to inject it as a dependency.
- Integrate the library with the AngularJS framework, which is often done by writing some [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Fortunately for you, Angular directives are already available for Chart.js, thanks to the [angular-chart.js library](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). You just need to configure RequireJS to load it. Add a `requireConfig` section to the manifest of one of your fragments:

```
{
  "id": "my-fragment",

  ...

  "requireConfig": {
    "paths": {
      "{angular-chart.js}": "${components-path:bower_components}/angular-chart.js/dist",
      "{chart.js}": "${components-path:bower_components}/chart.js/dist"
    },

    "map": {
      "{angular-chart.js}/angular-chart": {
        "angular": "{angular}/angular",
        "chart": "{chart.js}/Chart"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `paths` section declares locations of the two Chart.js libraries. Note that we use a variable named `components-path` with a default value of `bower_components` here. This is useful when using the [W20 bridge add-on](http://seedstack.org/addons/w20-bridge/).

The `map` section declares a mapping between the expected and the real paths for dependencies of angular-chart.js.

You can then use the angular-chart.js library according to its documentation:

```
define([
    '{angular}/angular',
    '{angular-chart.js}/angular-chart',
], function(angular) {
    var module = angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource', 'chart.js']); 

    module.controller('ContentController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
        // your JS code here 
        // (with your markup in a corresponding angular template)  
    }]);
});
```